# JSONObject Request does not get called frequently Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley, response, jsonobjectrequest

I have a JSONObjectRequest that wont get called everytime. So there will be no response. I also have another JSONObjectRequest that will always be called. Sometimes i change the code in the MainActivity and it will be called again and then not. The backend works just fine. Currently this is how the method looks like:

```
public void getPictureOfAllIngredients( final GetAllResponseListener callback){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    String url ="";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        String message = response.getString("message");
                        if(status.equals("success")){
                            callback.onResponse(response.toString());
                        }else{

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

This is how the method looks that calls it:

```
public void initDataIngredients() throws IOException {

    data = (ArrayList<IngredientEntity>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("ingredients", null));

    if( data == null  || data.size() == 0
    ){
        ingredientService.getPictureOfAllIngredients(new IngredientService.GetAllResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(String Message) {
                String x = Message;
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String Message) {
                mapper= new RecipeMapper();
                data = mapper.parseIngredientDatabaseEntityToRegularEntity(Message);
                try {
                    editor.putString("ingredients", ObjectSerializer.serialize(data)).apply();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
        data = (ArrayList<IngredientEntity>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("ingredients", null));
    }

}
```

And this is how the method looks that always gets called:

```
public void getAllRecipes( final GetAllResponseListener callback){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    String url ="";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        String message = response.getString("message");
                        if(status.equals("success")){
                            callback.onResponse(response.toString());
                        }else{

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

And this is how the method looks that calls the working request:

```
  public void initDataRecipes(){

    ArrayList<RecipeEntity> array = new ArrayList<RecipeEntity>();
    //if(sharedPreferences.getString("recipes",null) == null) {
        ingredientService.getAllRecipes(new IngredientService.GetAllResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(String Message) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String Message) {
                mapper= new RecipeMapper();
                recipes = mapper.parseRecipeDatabaseEntityToRegularEntity(Message);




                try {
                    editor.putString("ingredients", ObjectSerializer.serialize(data)).apply();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
```

J just cant figure out why one gets called an the other one not. I also looked up in the debugger where it goes and it just jumps the responses both. Any help will be much appreciated.

***EDIT***

I figured out the service gets only called when the onCreate method is called two times. So when i navigate out of the main page and navigate back into it, the service will be called. Any guesses??

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by myself.

The flaw was the async behavior of Volley. I set it by creating a **new Intent** and recalling the main activity `onResponse()`.